# Android RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

Tags: android, grid, android-recyclerview

Now I have changed grid to recyclerview grid, so I think all will be okay, but nope, I had one more problem. I was looking for same questions, try to fix my own problem, but nope, all doesn't help me.

```
Log:{

RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

}
```

So this is my code:

```
 Database database;
int mId;
boolean isFabOpen;
RecyclerViewGridODAdapter recyclerViewGridODAdapter;
AlertDialog.Builder myDialog;
int[]Ids;
GridAutofitLayoutManager layoutManager;
private Animation fab_open,fab_close,rotate_forward,rotate_backward;
List<OneDayTD> oneDayList;
private static final String TAG = "MyLog";
// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }

}

 @Override
public View onCreateView( LayoutInflater inflater,  ViewGroup container3,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v =inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one_day_tasks,container3,false);
    View vds =inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_fragment_one_day_tasks,null);
    final View vd =inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialogod,null);
    TextView textView= (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.ActiveMenu);
    TextView textView1= (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.Alert);
    database = new Database(v.getContext());
    mId = database.getLastIdOD();
    if(mId>=1) {
        oneDayList = database.getOneDayList(1);
    }
    database.close();

    //dlg1 = new DialogFragment();
    final RecyclerView gridView = (RecyclerView) vds.findViewById(R.id.gridViewActiveOd);

     layoutManager = new GridAutofitLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), 160 );
    if(0<mId){

        Log.d("myLog","StartAdapter");

        Log.d("myLog","oki "+oneDayList.get(0).getTitle());

       recyclerViewGridODAdapter =new RecyclerViewGridODAdapter(oneDayList);
        gridView.setAdapter(recyclerViewGridODAdapter);//RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
        gridView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);//RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
        gridView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        gridView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), gridView, new ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, final int position) {
                myDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

                FrameLayout layout =  (FrameLayout) vd.findViewById(R.id.dialogod);
                final FloatingActionButton tap = (FloatingActionButton) vd.findViewById(R.id.fabTap);
                fab_open = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.anim.fab_open);
                fab_close = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),R.anim.fab_close);
                rotate_forward = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),R.anim.rotate_forward);
                rotate_backward = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),R.anim.rotate_backward);
                final FloatingActionButton remake = (FloatingActionButton) layout.findViewById(R.id.fabRemake);
                remake.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        getActivity().finish();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),CreateOneDayActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("mId", oneDayList.get(position).getId());
                        startActivity(intent);

                        Snackbar.make(v, "Task Remake", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .setAction("Action", null).show();
                        gridView.refreshDrawableState();

                    }
                });
                final FloatingActionButton back = (FloatingActionButton) layout.findViewById(R.id.fabBack);
                back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        Snackbar.make(v, "Ok back", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .setAction("Action", null).show();

                    }
                });
                final FloatingActionButton del = (FloatingActionButton) layout.findViewById(R.id.fabDel);
                del.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        database = new Database(getActivity());
                        OneDayTD oneDayTD = database.getOneDay(oneDayList.get(position).getId());
                        database.deleteOD(oneDayTD);
                        Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), AlarmReceiver.class);
                        AlarmUtil.cancelAlarm(getActivity(), alarmIntent, oneDayTD.getId());
                        database.close();
                        Snackbar.make(v, "Ok you had put it int the del folder? bit rot some little time", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .setAction("Action", null).show();
                    }
                });
                final FloatingActionButton copy = (FloatingActionButton) layout.findViewById(R.id.fabClone);
                copy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        database = new Database(getActivity());
                        OneDayTD oneDayTD = database.getOneDay(oneDayList.get(position).getId());
                        oneDayTD.setId(oneDayList.get(position).getId() + 1);
                        database.addOT(oneDayTD);
                        database.close();
                        Snackbar.make(v, "Ok you had copy that task", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .setAction("Action", null).show();

                    }
                });
                tap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if(isFabOpen){

                            tap.startAnimation(rotate_backward);
                            copy.startAnimation(fab_close);
                            del.startAnimation(fab_close);
                            remake.startAnimation(fab_close);
                            back.startAnimation(fab_close);

                            copy.setClickable(false);
                            del.setClickable(false);
                            remake.setClickable(false);
                            back.setClickable(false);
                            isFabOpen = false;


                        } else {

                            tap.startAnimation(rotate_forward);
                            copy.startAnimation(fab_open);
                            del.startAnimation(fab_open);
                            remake.startAnimation(fab_open);
                            back.startAnimation(fab_open);

                            copy.setClickable(true);
                            del.setClickable(true);
                            remake.setClickable(true);
                            back.setClickable(true);


                            isFabOpen = true;


                        }
                    }
                });
                CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout = (CoordinatorLayout) layout.findViewById(R.id.dialoodcontent);
                TextView title = (TextView) coordinatorLayout.findViewById(R.id.title_dialogod);
                title.setText(oneDayList.get(position).getTitle());
                TextView content = (TextView) coordinatorLayout.findViewById(R.id.tcontent);
                content.setText(oneDayList.get(position).getContent());
                TextView date= (TextView)coordinatorLayout.findViewById(R.id.date);
                date.setText(oneDayList.get(position).getDate());
                TextView time= (TextView) coordinatorLayout.findViewById(R.id.time);
                time.setText(oneDayList.get(position).getTime());
                ImageView imageView = (ImageView) coordinatorLayout.findViewById(R.id.imagepart);
                ImageView imageView1 = (ImageView) coordinatorLayout.findViewById(R.id.circle);
                int iconResId = getActivity().getResources().getIdentifier(oneDayList.get(position).getIcon(), "drawable", getActivity().getPackageName());
                imageView.setImageResource(iconResId);
                GradientDrawable bgShape = (GradientDrawable) imageView1.getDrawable();
                bgShape.setColor(Color.parseColor(oneDayList.get(position).getColour()));
                SeekBar seekBar = (SeekBar) coordinatorLayout.findViewById(R.id.volumeSelectSeek);
                seekBar.setMax(15);
                seekBar.setProgress(oneDayList.get(position).getVolume());
                seekBar.isSaveEnabled();
                TextView realmel = (TextView) coordinatorLayout.findViewById(R.id.truemelody);
                realmel.setText(oneDayList.get(position).getSound()+"("+oneDayList.get(position).getDirSound()+")");
                TextView typeofs= (TextView) coordinatorLayout.findViewById(R.id.toss);
                int v=oneDayList.get(position).getVibration();
                if(v==1){
                    typeofs.setText("Vibaration");
                }
                int os=oneDayList.get(position).getOriginalSound();
                if(os==1){
                    String i ="";
                    if(typeofs.getText().toString().isEmpty())
                    {
                        typeofs.setText("Sound");
                    }else{
                        i=typeofs.getText().toString() + " and ";
                        typeofs.setText(i+"Sound");
                    }
                }
                int wh=oneDayList.get(position).getWhistling();
                if(wh==1){
                    String i ="";
                    if(typeofs.getText().toString().isEmpty())
                    {
                        typeofs.setText("Whistle");
                    }else{
                        i=typeofs.getText().toString() + " and ";
                        typeofs.setText(i+"Whistle");
                    }
                }else{

                }
                myDialog.setView(layout);
                myDialog.show();

                //Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),CreateOneDayActivity.class);
                // intent.putExtra("mId",oneDayList.get(position).getId());
                // startActivity(intent);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {

            }
        }));



    }else{
        textView1.setText("You Haven't got any Active Tasks !");
    }

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) v.findViewById(R.id.fabCreateOd);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            getActivity().finish();
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),CreateOneDayActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("mId",1 + database.getLastIdOD());
            startActivity(intent);
            Snackbar.make(view, "New Task", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
    return v;
}
public interface ClickListener {
    void onClick(View view, int position);

    void onLongClick(View view, int position);
}

public static class RecyclerTouchListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {

    private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
    private ClickListener clickListener;

    public RecyclerTouchListener(Context context, final RecyclerView recyclerView, final ClickListener clickListener) {
        this.clickListener = clickListener;
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
                View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
                if (child != null && clickListener != null) {
                    clickListener.onLongClick(child, recyclerView.getChildPosition(child));
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

        View child = rv.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
        if (child != null && clickListener != null && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
            clickListener.onClick(child, rv.getChildPosition(child));
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Please try posting a [MCVE]. It will really help people read your code and answer your questions.

Answer (score 1):

Put

```
recyclerViewGridODAdapter =new RecyclerViewGridODAdapter(oneDayList);
```

in `onCreateView()` instead of `onCreate()` like this .

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView( LayoutInflater inflater,  ViewGroup container3,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
.....
    if(mId>=1) {
            oneDayList = database.getOneDayList(1);
        }
    recyclerViewGridODAdapter =new RecyclerViewGridODAdapter(oneDayList); 
...
}
```

The error is because `oneDayList` is empty when you are creating your adapter. You  should either create your adapter in `onCreateView()` (as shown above) or refresh your adapter after you get values in `oneDayList`.

Comment: Then check if "oneDayList" is empty or not after you call database.getOneDayList(1);

Comment: Gui i had check oneDayList , bit it still doesn't work...... But all was well with Adapter and onedaylist..... So i haven't got any idea what was happend .......

Comment: How come your are inflating 3 views in one fragment - View v =inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one_day_tasks,container3,false);
    View vds =inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_fragment_one_day_tasks,null);
    final View vd =inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialogod,null); First inflate only one view which you need.

Comment: I create a new one with the same error , but also i have change some views

Comment: Update your code by inflating only one view which you need.